# Non-disjoint cycle multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

We are working with $S_{10}$, the group of permutations of $\{1,...,20\}$, and $\sigma=(a_1 ,...,a_{10})$ and $\pi=(b_1 , ..., b_3)$. We wish to find the order of $\sigma^2$, and  $\sigma^3$.

Can't we just start by stating the order of $\sigma$ is just $10$ because the cardinality of $\sigma$ is $10$.

Isn't $\sigma^2 = (a_1 , ..., a_{10})(a_1 , ... ,a_{10})$, and since there are repeats all throughout the multiplication the order of $\sigma^2$ is also $10$.

If not then what am I missing? Wouldn't the case for $\sigma^3$ just be the same thing as well.

Comment: Why not try the example s= (1,2,...,10). Then you can work out s squared explicitly and find its order

Comment: I might just be confused on order in general then, but when I computed s^2 explicitly, we get 1->3, 2->4, 3->5, 4->6, 5->7,6->8,7->9,8->10,9->1,10->2. how would I calculate order from this?

Comment: it might help to find the cycle notation for $s^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True it is that since $\sigma$ is a $10$-cycle its order is $10$.  But then $\sigma^2$ has order $5$.  Meanwhile, $\sigma^3$ has order $10$ again, because $\rm{gcd}(3,10)=1$.

General fact about cyclic groups, if $g$ has order $n$, then $g^k$ has order $n/\rm{gcd}(n,k)$.

Finally, what does $\pi$ have to do with it?

Comment: I'm self studying Goodmans abstract algebra, and we had to find $\sigma\pi$ but I was able to do that part of it, and I just included it in the question. I just saw that lemma in the book you're talking about, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure Logan. You bet.

Comment: Can you explain why $\sigma^2$ would not be 10, I see with the use of the fact that we would in fact get 5, but if sigma has order 10, sigma*sigma, is just a rearrangement of those 10 terms. But in general we would still have cardinality 10, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe write it out.  $(12345678910)(12345678910)=(13579)(2468 10)$.  So, you get the product of two disjoint five cycles.